# jQuery using Ajax inside widget cannot set options properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, widget

I'm trying to create a widget, and let it take care of its own ajax call, and do stuff with the data coming back after, however, i can't seems to be able to set the options internally?

```
$.widget("test" , {
    options: {
        url : null,
        data : null
    },
    _create: function() {
        var that = this;


        $.ajax({
            url : this.options.url,
            dataType : 'json',
            cache : false
        }).done(function(resp) {
            that._option("data", resp.stuff);

        });

        this._blah();
    },
    _option: function(key, val) {
        this.options[key] = val;
    },
    _blah: function() {
        console.log(this.options.data);
    }
}
```

the variable `url` is being set when the widget is triggered. I can't use `this` inside ajax, so i created `that` instead. But the `data` won't stick....

Also the weird thing is that, if i put a breakpoint inside the widget, the breakpoint would get trigger for the first time, but not the second... is there a better way to debug the jQuery widget?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. you're executing _blah before the request has finished, which is also before the done callback gets executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: oh shoot, thank! bookmarked the other link. -_-"